# Ordenar array por dos propiedades

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, objeto, ecmascript-6

Tengo un array con objectos que tienen el siguiente formato:

```
{
  "username": "Antonio",
  "bot": false
}
```

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
guild.members.sort((a, b) => a.user.username > b.user.username ? 1 : -1);
```

En el cual, ordena el array en orden alfabético, sin embargo, quiero que los usuarios cuya propiedad `bot` sea `true` salgan primeros, en orden alfabético.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisa esta [página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control):

En ella explican como hacer la función compareFunction que le pasas por parametro a metodo sort().

```
function compare(a, b) {
  // Comparamos la propiedad bot de user.

  if (a.user.bot < b.user.bot) return 1;
  if (a.user.bot > b.user.bot) return -1;
  else {
    // Si la propiedad bot de user es igual, ordenar alfabéticamente.

    if (a.user.username > b.user.username) return 1;
    else if (a.user.username < b.user.username) return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Este código debería funcionar pero no lo he llegado a probar.

Comment: Functiona. Este código es mucho más eficiente. https://jsfiddle.net/6dt7skg9/

Answer (score 1):

> quiero que los usuarios cuya propiedad bot sea true salgan primeros, **en orden alfabético.**

Para manejar ambos criterios al mismo tiempo, puedes ordenarlo 2 veces. Dependiendo de la cantidad de registros puede ser una alternativa facil de mantener.

Ej.

```js
var members = [
  { bot: false, user: { name: "Bbbbb" }},
  { bot: true, user: { name: "Baaaaa" }},
  { bot: true, user: { name: "Bbbbb" }},
  { bot: false, user: { name: "Baaaaa" }},
  { bot: true, user: { name: "Aaba" }},
  { bot: true, user: { name: "Aaaa" }},
  { bot: false, user: { name: "Aaba" }},
  { bot: false, user: { name: "Aaaa" }}
];

var ordenado = members.sort((a, b) => a.user.username > b.user.username ? -1 : 1)
                      .sort((a, b) => +b.bot-a.bot);

console.log(ordenado);
```

Nota: el + convierte el booleano a number haciendo mas facil la comparacion del caso donde ambos booleanos son iguales.